# #if preprocessor directive doesn't always collapse

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, preprocessor-directive

Say I define two #define preprocessor directives:

```
#define TEST
#define TESTOFF
```

Now my code is organized in TEST and TESTOFF #if directives, e.g.:

```
#if TEST
    ...
#endif

...MORE CODE...

#if TESTOFF
    ...
#endif
```

It often happens that one `#if` region, say the `#if TEST` region, becomes collapsible while the other (`#if TESTOFF` region) is not.

Since this is a strange phenomenon that some might've never encountered, I'm appending a snapshot of the issue in question:
[image: Alternating collapsible #if regions]

Does anyone know what parameters define this behavior behavior of the `#if` preprocessor directive?

Comment: I don't think, it is possible to collapse #if - #endif. This is part of code. You can't collapse code. You can collapse only regions and definitions. Even attributes are sticking out

Comment: Do post valid code, this doesn't compile.  Won't collapse either.  Nor is it supposed to.

Comment: Why would you complain that pseudocode doesn't compile? That's totally irrelevant to the question asked.

Comment: @T.S. At first I thought the same. But then, _all of a sudden_ I had collapsible regions inside `#if` `#endif` blocks. I added a picture to clarify.

Comment: @GrantWinney Nope, I'm not confusing the two different directives, but I do agree that the phenomenon I describe is **weird**. I updated with a picture. Check it out.

Comment: I would have thought that collapse might be offered for undefined preprocessor variables (since they contain entirely dead code) but conventional collapse would be offered for live code. Is your experience different?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever You're right!! When I kill a `#define` the `#if` block becomes collapsible. Please do post that as an answer!

Comment: @Seabiscuit So, in the end, you didn't have collapsible `#if`. That was your inactive code collapsible - that is different, my friend, and you didn't clearly stated that from the beginning

Comment: @T.S. I think the exact description is more subjective than semantic. But if it makes you happy...

Comment: @Seabiscuit "the #if TEST region, becomes collapsible" - that is wrong explanation. `#if` itself never became collapsible

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the `#If` test is false, then obviously all of the code within (no matter what it's structure may be) is dead code. It makes sense to offer to collapse these sections.

If the `#If` test is true, then arbitrary code may be contained within. So the collapse options are based on the *code* structure. And no collapse is offered on the arbitrary `#If` test.

Answer (score 4):

Damien_The_Unbeliever's comment is correct. VS provides the collapse feature for sections that are inactive with your current settings (the parts that are shown in gray), and does not provide them for the active parts. So if I had this code:

```
#if DEBUG
     string a = "2";
     string b = "3";
#else
     string a = "3";
     string b = "3";
#endif
```

The bottom part would be collapsible while I have the Debug configuration active, but the top would become collapsible (and the bottom un-collapsible) if I switch it over to Release.

Answer (score 0):

As a simple workaround to issues and/or personal preferences with collapsing it's worth noting that you can wrap any block of code in braces {} and VS will make it a collapsable region.